# Image fails to work as a mask with Core Graphics

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, mask, masking

I am having some trouble masking a UIImage using another UIImage as a mask. I've tried using the `masking(_:)` Core Graphics function (`CGImageCreateWithMask` in Objective C), but the output for the masked image shows no masking whatsoever. It just shows the normal image.

I've used two methods to do this: First, applying by passing along the mask image itself. Second, by using the `CGImage` initializer to create a mask from that image and passing it instead. Here is the function that does this:

```
func performMask(_ originalImage:UIImage, maskImage:UIImage) -> UIImage? {
    guard let originalImageCGImage = originalImage.cgImage, let maskImageCGImage = maskImage.cgImage else { return nil }

    print("Method 1 - Image (UIImage):")
    print("\(String(describing: maskImage.cgImage))\n\n")

    print("Method 2 - Mask (CGImage):")

    let maskImage2 = CGImage(
        maskWidth: Int(maskImage.size.width * maskImage.scale),
        height: Int(maskImage.size.height * maskImage.scale),
        bitsPerComponent: maskImageCGImage.bitsPerComponent,
        bitsPerPixel: maskImageCGImage.bitsPerPixel,
        bytesPerRow: maskImageCGImage.bytesPerRow,
        provider: maskImageCGImage.dataProvider!,
        decode: nil,
        shouldInterpolate: true
    )

    print("\(String(describing: maskImage2))\n\n")

    let maskedImage     = originalImageCGImage.masking(maskImage.cgImage!)  // Output: Method 1
//  let maskedImage2    = originalImageCGImage.masking(maskImage2!)         // Output: Method 2

    return UIImage(cgImage: maskedImage!)
}
```

Here is the console output I get, showing the print statements above:

```
Method 1 - Image (UIImage):
Optional(<CGImage 0x104223890> (DP)
    <<CGColorSpace 0x281414960> (kCGColorSpaceICCBased; kCGColorSpaceModelMonochrome; Generic Gray Gamma 2.2 Profile)>
        width = 320, height = 320, bpc = 8, bpp = 8, row bytes = 640 
        kCGImageAlphaNone | 0 (default byte order)  | kCGImagePixelFormatPacked 
        is mask? No, has masking color? No, has soft mask? No, has matte? No, should interpolate? Yes)


Method 2 - Mask (CGImage):
Optional(<CGImage 0x104223e90> (DP)
    <(null)>
        width = 320, height = 320, bpc = 8, bpp = 8, row bytes = 640 
        kCGImageAlphaNone | 0 (default byte order)  | kCGImagePixelFormatPacked 
        is mask? Yes, has masking color? No, has soft mask? No, has matte? No, should interpolate? Yes)
```

A theory I have is that the image being in the `kCGColorSpaceModelMonochrome` color space is the problem. The documentation for the `masking(_:)` function says:

> "If the mask is an image, it must be in the DeviceGray color space,
> must not have an alpha component, and may not itself be masked by an
> image mask or a masking color."

However, the headers give a less stringent color space requirement:

> "If `mask' is an image, then it must be in a monochrome color space
> (e.g. DeviceGray, GenericGray, etc...), may not have alpha, and may
> not itself be masked by an image mask or a masking color."

No matter what I do, I am only ever to get a `kCGColorSpaceModelMonochrome` color space for my mask image (not DeviceGray) - which *should* work based on the latter statement, but not the first.

The mask image itself is generated from a `UIBezierPath` using `UIGraphicsImageRenderer`'s `image(actions: (UIGraphicsImageRendererContext) -> Void)` function, and it looks okay to me in the debugger (it's an irregularly-shaped black-and-white image) - it just doesn't work as a mask.

Note: I am attempting to benefit from the iOS 12 memory usage optimizations in `UIGraphicsImageRenderer` detailed in 2018's WWDC talk *'Image and Graphics Best Practices'* (29:15), but unfortunately have no way to manually specify the color space of the resultant image. This is framed as a feature but I wish there was a way to override it.

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/219/

Does anyone know how to get this mask operation to work properly?

Comment: Why do need this masked UIImage? You could try setting CALayer's mask, if this is some custom UIView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, the mask needs to be in color space DeviceGray. The good news is that you can easily generate a mask in DeviceGray, you just can't use `UIGraphicsImageRenderer`. Let's implement a type that generates a mask in DeviceGray and accepts a closure that allows you to draw whatever mask you like.

```
struct MaskRenderer {
    let size: CGSize
    let scale: CGFloat

    var sizeInPixels: CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: size.width * scale, height: size.height * scale)
    }

    func image(actions: (CGContext) -> Void) -> UIImage? {
        let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray()

        guard let context = CGContext.init(
            data: nil,
            width: Int(sizeInPixels.width),
            height: Int(sizeInPixels.height),
            bitsPerComponent: 8,
            bytesPerRow: 0,
            space: colorSpace,
            bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.none.rawValue
            ) else { return nil }

        actions(context)

        guard let coreImageMask = context.makeImage() else { return nil }

        return UIImage(cgImage: coreImageMask)
    }
}
```

Let's also implement a `UIImage` extension that applies a mask to the receiver, returning the masked image:

```
extension UIImage {
    func withMask(_ imageMask: UIImage) -> UIImage? {
        guard let coreImage = cgImage else { return nil }
        guard let coreImageMask = imageMask.cgImage else { return nil }
        guard let coreMaskedImage = coreImage.masking(coreImageMask) else { return nil }

        return UIImage(cgImage: coreMaskedImage)
    }
}
```

Now we can draw and apply the mask to an arbitrary image:

```
func applyMask(to image: UIImage) -> UIImage? {
    let renderer = MaskRenderer(size: image.size, scale: image.scale)
    guard let imageMask = renderer.image(actions: { context in
        let rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: renderer.sizeInPixels)
            .insetBy(dx: 0, dy: renderer.sizeInPixels.height / 4)
        let path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: rect)
        context.addPath(path.cgPath)
        context.setFillColor(gray: 1, alpha: 1)
        context.drawPath(using: .fillStroke)
    }) else { return nil }
    return image.withMask(imageMask)
}
```

All you have to do is replace the bezier path with yours.

Comment: Hi Robert - thanks for the tip!

I gave this a shot but, unfortunately, it seems that the mask image generated (by `image(actions:..)`) is still coming across as `kCGColorSpaceModelMonochrome` for some reason.

I verified this both on-device and in an Xcode playground. I also verified that the `context.colorSpace` is `kCGColorSpaceDeviceGray` - it's just that the mask image that is created isn't.

Unfortunately, the mask still doesn't apply to the image. It remains unchanged.

Comment: @JeffC. Strange. Have you tried testing with a different image?